# How to export crosstab to csv

Tags: r, export, data-analysis, crosstab, summary

I have a dataset, where I run this code:

```
source("http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~william/R/crosstab.r")
crosstab(nautos, row.vars = "s2_nautos_voor", col.vars = "s2_nautos_nu", type = "t")
```

And get this result:

```
               s2_nautos_nu      0      1     2+    Sum
s2_nautos_voor                                         
0                            19.89   3.31   0.05  23.25
1                             0.92  51.71   1.78  54.41
2+                            0.31   2.45  19.58  22.34
Sum                          21.11  57.47  21.42 100.00
```

However, when I try to save it in a csv using this code:

```
crosstabs_nautos <- crosstab(nautos, row.vars = "s2_nautos_voor", col.vars = "s2_nautos_nu", type = "t")
write.csv(crosstabs_nautos$table,"crosstabs_nautos.csv")
```

It gets saved with the type = f instead of t. In other words, it doesn't save the function, and I get this:

```
               s2_nautos_nu    0    1   2+  Sum
s2_nautos_voor                                 
0                            390   65    1  456
1                             18 1014   35 1067
2+                             6   48  384  438
Sum                          414 1127  420 1961
```

...no matter which crosstab function I apply.

How can I get around this?

Comment: @akrun added the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the `crosstabs` function only stores the table as frequencies in an object of class crosstabs and  then "prints" with desired type to the console with an associated S3 `print.crosstabs` function that checks for the type before "deciding" whether to print raw frequencies or percentages. If you only send the "table" leaf of the list structure to write.csv, then there is no opportunity to check the type. Perhaps you are expected to figure this out by experimentation or by reading the code. I cannot find any documentation of that set of functions at that academic website. If you have any links to documentation, then you should include them in your question.

Also, most of the checks in the code are of thesort:

```
if ( type="frequency") {   do something
```

So they are written to be exact checks and the spelling would need to be exact rather than abbreviated. You could use `capture.output` to send the results of `print.crosstabs` to a file. It won't be csv delimited. However that might not be a problem since there don't appear to be commas in the output you are concerned about. Try

```
 capture.output( print(crosstabs_nautos, type = "frequencies") , 
               file="crosstabs_nautos.txt")
```

Or you could perhaps write.csv using the object `crosstab_nautos$table/1961`

Edit: There's some code near the end of the crosstabs function that's making me think my guesses were not completely correct:

```
 #(b) tabular output [3 variants]
    result$table <- tbl  #Stores original cross-tab frequency counts without margins [class: table]
    result$crosstab <- crosstab #Stores cross-tab in table format using requested style(frequency/pct) and table margins (on/off)
                                #[class: table]  
    result$crosstab.nosub <- t1  #crosstab with subtotals suppressed [class: dataframe; or NULL if no subtotals suppressed]  
    class(result) <- "crosstab"
```

Comment: If I wanted to use your bottom answer, what would I need to write to execute it for my code?

Comment: create a "normalized" table: `ptbl <- crosstab_nautos$table/1961`, then use `write.csv`.

Comment: That works, although the numbers are slightly different.

Comment: Perhaps `ptbl <- crosstab_nautos$table/sum(crosstab_nautos$table)` would be more general? You need to decide whether you want the margins. If you do then: `ptbl <- crosstab_nautos$crosstabs/sum(crosstab_nautos$table)` . It's the `$table`-item that is the freq table without the margins.

Comment: Using the first of the two and saving it to csv gives me a csv where the total sum is 0.25 and using the second and saving it to csv gives me a csv where the only content is an "x" on second colum row 1.

Comment: By asking questions without a MCVE you can only get ... untested code. You could multiply the first result by 4. There are apparently 4 representation of the counts, 1 in the cells, 2 in the margins and one in the corner grand total. (I thought the `table` element` only had the cell counts.)

Comment: Thank you. I eventually found a way around these issues by avoiding this crosstab() function.

Comment: there is a `table` function and table objects can be augmented with the `add.margins` function